# Vue dynamic form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a dynamic form that the user can input an item, the quantity required and the cost per item as shown below:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submit">

  <div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.item">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.quantity">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.cost">
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" @click="remove(k)" v-show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)">Remove</i>
      <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" @click="add(k)" v-show="k == inputs.length-1">Add fields</i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

I want to calculate the total of cost of all the items added. I've tried

```js
export default {
  methods: {
      totalCost: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++) {
              return this.inputs[i].cost*this.inputs[i].quantity
          }
      }
  }
}
```

but this just gives me the total cost of the first item. How do I go about getting the total cost of all the items input by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement inside your `for`-loop causes it to return immediately after calculating the cost of the first item.

A quick fix is to remove that `return`, and accumulate the sum total using a local variable:

```js
let total = 0
for (let i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++){
  total += this.inputs[i].cost * this.inputs[i].quantity
}
return total
```